# Detect if Capability is enabled

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

My app needs the [capability](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt270968.aspx) to access user account information. There fore I added

```
<Capabilities>
    <uap:Capability Name="userAccountInformation"/>
</Capabilities>
```

to the package.appxmanifest.

Is there a way to check if the user disallowed this capability?

Comment: When setting the required capabilities  and starting the app the first time, it asks for accessing information/data of the user account. The pop up provides yes or no. If you don't enable the Capability userAccountInformation you can execute the method User.GetFromId().GetPropertiesAsync()but it will return only a empty result set.

Comment: Thanks.  Getting an empty set is a pretty good cue.

Answer (score 0):

In windows 8 you must use 
[NameAccessAllowed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.userprofile.userinformation.nameaccessallowed)

```
if ( !UserInformation.NameAccessAllowed )
{
}
```

there are not equivalent to NameAccessAllowed

But The UserInformation class is not supported on Windows 10 or later. Use the User class instead.

Windows 10:
Apps compiled for Windows 8 that use the UserInformation class no longer return user information when running on Windows 10. This is because in Windows 10, apps do not have access to user information without explicit user consent, unlike in Windows 8 where this permission is granted by default.

[Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.userprofile.userinformation)